# EXCEL how to set cell row from other cell value

Tags: excel

Is there a way for me to set a row value from another cell value.

Example:
A1 = B62 = 'HELLO'

C1 = 62

So instead of 62 I want to set the value of C1.

A1 = B(C1) which would equal B62.

I hope I explained it well :P

Update:
This is the formula bar: `=SUMIF('I1'!$C$2:$C$61,A2,'I1'!$F$2:$F$61)`
Want to change the both 61 to my V4 cell value. For example if V4 = 10.
That would make `=SUMIF('I1'!$C$2:$C$10,A2,'I1'!$F$2:$F$10)`

Comment: What do you want to do? A formula for `A1`, that returns the value showing in `C1`?  BUT using `B62` somehow?  Does `B62` have "HELLO" In the cell?  I think you're going to want `Indirect()`, but I'm not sure how...can you perhaps explain further, or show an example?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me! , I want control the formula bar from a cell value. Instead of changing every time the B62 to B20, B30 etc. I want the formula bar to get the value of C1 which will be a number that will indicate which row of B will it take. So if I set the C1 value to 15. Then the Formula bar of A1 will equal to B15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the non volatile INDEX()

```
=SUMIF('I1'!C$2:INDEX('I1'!$C:$C,$V$4),A2,'I1'!F$2:INDEX('I1'!$F:$F,$V$4))
```

Comment: Copy pasted it. Did not work. Still trying to figure out what the problem might be. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Is the sheet name `l1` or `I1`? `l` as in lower case `L` or `I` as in upper case `i`? @AresProductions

Comment: it is upper case i

Comment: @AresProductions I had the sheet names wrong, see edit.

Comment: That was it!. Thanks you so much everyone!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121090/discussion-between-aresproductions-and-scott-craner).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Indirect.

In `C1`, place your row value (`15`, for example).  Then, in cell `A1`, use `=Indirect("B" & $C$1)`

Then as you change the value in `C1`, the value in `A1` will change.

Comment: This is my formula bar
=SUMIF('I1'!$C$2:$C$61,A2,'I1'!$F$2:$F$61),
I set it like this and its not working. Maybe my syntax is wrong?
=SUMIF('I1'!$C$2:INDIRECT("C" & $V$4),A2,'I1'!$F$2:$F$61)

Comment: @AresProductions is `I1` the name of the sheet or the cell in which the name of the sheet is found?

Comment: I want to change that :$C$61 to my V4 value, 
I1 is the name of the sheet. But my V4 value is on the current sheet. (not I1)

Comment: @AresProductions - Woah, where did that come from? Could you please put your formula in your OP? Although I bet ScotCraner's solution works for you. I didn't know you were doing this inside a formula.

Comment: If the sheet name is not `l1` and is in fact the cell in which the sheet name resides then INDIRECT will be the only way to go.

Comment: $C$61 is in I1 sheet, but V4  is on the current sheet.